# error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<Wire, std::allocator<Wire> >::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<Wire>&, Wire&)’

Tags: c++, c++11

```
if (iter->tokenType==Token::NAME && wstate==WIRE)
{
   wstate=WIRENAME;
   Wire tempwire;
   tempwire.Name=iter->token;
   tempwire.width=bus_msb;
   std::list<Wire>::const_iterator witer = LargestWireName(tempwire,tempModule.wires);
   if (witer!=tempModule.wires.end())
   {
       tempModule.wires.insert(witer,tempwire);
   }
   else
   {
       tempModule.wires.push_back(tempwire);
   }
}
```

When I try calling the insert function for wires, i am getting this error...

error: no matching function for call to `‘std::list<Wire, std::allocator<Wire> >::insert(std::_List_const_iterator<Wire>&, Wire&)’`

can anyone help?? please

Comment: please no screenshot of code.

Comment: Is it really easier to take a screenshot, upload it to the internet, and link it here than copy and paste your code?

Comment: you are using the c++11 signature with a compiler which is not c++11

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. I am new to this website.

Comment: Thank you UmNyobe, but I am not familiar with c++11. So could you help me with a solution please. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the c++11 signature off [std::list::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) with a compiler which is not c++11.
Prior to c++11 you should have

```
std::list<Wire>::iterator witer;
```

instead of

```
std::list<Wire>::const_iterator witer
```

If the code is intended to be c++11, make sure the compiler is compatible and has the feature enabled. Due to the error message format I assume this is gcc. Thus use `-std=c++11` in the build command.

Comment: this change gives me another error
remote: build-tmp/src/bonus.cpp:289: error: conversion from ‘std::_List_const_iterator<Wire>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::_List_iterator<Wire>’ requested

Comment: if I convert all the const_iterator to iterator, will the problem be solved?

Comment: the earlier problem got solved but now its showing me another problem.

error: conversion from ‘std::_List_const_iterator<Wire>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::_List_iterator<Wire>’ requested